# Codeblocks isn't showing graphics window

Tags: c++, bgi, winbgi

I have tried to learn about graphics using codeblocks , and have initialized the graphics header to my library , every graphics code builds and compiles , and shows :

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.776 s
Press any key to continue.
```

but it doesn't show the graphic window. For example I have written a code to show lines, it doesn't show anything.

I tried this code at first, and it showed:

> F:\Code blocks\Lab final\Graph.cpp|12|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|

Here is the code:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int  main() {
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode;
    int x1 = 200, y1 = 200;
    int x2 = 300, y2 = 300;
    char driver[] =  "";
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode,driver);
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

I expected to see the graphics window , but it doesn't show anything .

Comment: Note that with `int gdriver = DETECT, gmode;` the `DETECT` would be simply ignored.

Comment: Have you tried checking these function calls for errors according to their documentation?

Comment: yeah , when compiling this code it doesn't show any errors .

Comment: That's not what I mean. Look up documentation for each function call and check at runtime to make sure the call succeeded or which error it failed with.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: The graphics.h file will simply not work on modern versions of Windows - forget about using it.

Comment: It's up to the author of `initgraph` etc. to write documentation about how to use it. Find that documentation and consult it for how to do error checking.

Comment: if I write `initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode,"");` it shows errors .

Comment: @IsraqAhmedAnik I don't think the compiler CodeBlocks ships with has `graphics.h` installed by default. Did you download it separately?

Comment: yeah I have downloaded them , I think I am having problem with `pathtodriver`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What should I do then ?

Comment: Where did you download it? Did you change your compiler settings to make the code compile? If so, how exactly? Those details might be important.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have downloaded it from [link](http://www.codecutter.net/tools/winbgim/) here , and copied graphics and winbgim to **MinGW\\include** and the _libbgi.a_ file to **MinGW\\lib** and then go to _Codeblocks>settings>compiler>Linkerlibraries_ and add the libbgi file and paste this : `-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32
` in other linker options and hit ok .

Answer (score 0):

- if you have tried a lot and not getting how to completely setup graphics in code block then you are at right place.

1).First delete your codeblock

2).Then install mingw-get-setup (32 bit) and setup it using any youtube video. If you have already installed it than it's fine. You can skip this step.

You can Use following link to download mingw(avoid if you already have it).

[Mingw-get-setup Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download)

3).Now install 32 bit version of codeblocks with mingw setup

[Download CodeBlocks 32 bit with mingw](https://excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/20.03/Windows/codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe)

- Now If you are Have Installed Ming-W in you C drive check that Your code block is by default taking compiler path as this c drive's MingW's path otherwise do reset default setting in codeblocks ->**settings-compiler-toolchain executable**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m469n.png)

- Then Go In the incude section of that C drive Mingw's include section **rather than going in codeblocks mingw's include section**
  now paste following files

  **Note**:- If You Have Already copied  graphics.h and winbgim.h files from other sources Then Also Replace It With Following

**Note**:- Best way to find include section is go in **C drive-Mingw** and type  **iostream**  in search bar of your file explorer and right click on iostream file and open its location and to find correct lib go back from this include section and click on lib section NOTE:-Location of lib may differ but correct lib is lib section with lot .a files

1 [Link Of Graphics.h File From Israq ahemad drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rv8ocZkTIQkemOcPBETL2YUGGCi6ovLx/view?usp=sharing)

2 [Link Of Winbgi.h File From Israq ahemad drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFZ6gP1Lm1PrmQkFkp1Pa4defGLpJHnD/view?usp=sharing)

- Now Go In that C drive Mingw's Lib section **rather than going in codeblock's mingw's lib section** and paste following file in that.

3[Link Of libbgi.a File From Israq ahemad drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkkNyreSy8Kn32SsO6IBkemyeMHX73rd/view?usp=sharing)

- Now Go to **setting-compiler-linkersetting**
  and in **linkersetting** add **libbgi.a** file location which you have just pasted
  and in right side box paste **-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32**

[Image that Shows Where To Add libbgi.a path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOa3f.png)

- And Now Just Try To Write

> 

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int gd,gm;
    detectgraph(&gd,&gm);
    initgraph(&gd,&gm," ");
    circle(200,200,100);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

in file with cpp extention.

And you will get following output

[Image that Shows Desired Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Alro.png)

Answer (score -2):

After trying a lot of sites I have found one from where downloading the files that can solve that issue , 
and for anyone that are facing the same problem , you can download the files from  [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1SDzX_JWl89S_BTuYOZ8ctXTc-jQV2N1e)
 and follow the steps from the read me file , and it will be solved .

And thanks to everyone who tried  to help and replied to my  question .